# A line is coming in the middle of my fragment screen after Android studio Hedgehog Patch 1 update. Any way to remove this

Tags: android, android-studio

[Image of the line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuJE8.png) After updating to Android studio Hedgehog Patch 1 a random line has appeared on screen and it is very distracting . Any fixes for this

I tried invalidating caches and even updating to Iguana still the issue persists and the line is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the line: `File > Settings > Editor > General > Appearance > Show hard wrap and visual guides`.

This line is present by default (even in earlier versions of `Android Studio`, this has nothing to do with Hedgehog Patch 1!) and has its origins in the time (~1970) when programmers still worked with punched cards and were **forced** to make a line break after 80 characters. See the following historical image [(image source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:FortranCardPROJ039.agr.jpg):

[image]

Many programmers have gotten used to this and need it as a reminder to make a line break soon to avoid having to scroll the code horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

---

##### It could be appear for various reasons, some solutions I can suggest is bellow:

---

**1. Inspect Editor Settings:**

- Right Margin: Go to `File > Settings > Editor > General > Appearance` and
  uncheck `"Show right margin"`
- Visual Guides and Indent Guides: In the same Appearance settings, uncheck
  "Show
  visual guides" and "Show indent guides."
- Soft Wraps: If the line appears at a specific character length, consider
  adjusting the soft wrap settings in File > Settings > Editor > General > Soft
  Wraps.

**2. Reset Android Studio Settings:**

- Go to `Help > Find Action (Ctrl+Shift+A or Cmd+Shift+A)`, type `"Reset  Settings"` and select `"Restore Default Settings"`

**3. Reinstall Android Studio:**

- If none of the above solutions work, a complete reinstallation might be necessary. Uninstall Android Studio, delete any leftover files and folders, and then reinstall it from the official website.

*Hope it helps!*